# Проблема с манифестом при сборке решения Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Добрый день! При попытке собрать решение Windows Forms Visual Studio возвращает ошибку "Невозможно прочитать манифест "obj\Debug\ProjectName.exe.manifest". Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb91a971fb93446e6b2e45d0cb8aa3b8c.tmp", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Удали все из папки obj\Debug\ и попробуй пересобрать решение.

Comment: Не помогло. Проблема осталась.

Answer (score 0):

После установки VS 2017 Community проблема исчезла. Проконсультировался по данному вопросу с инструкторами Microsoft, сказали что подозрение падает на MSBuild. Если проблема повторится, необходимо запустить диспетчер задач и в случае запуска нескольких экземпляров MSBuild необходимо их завершить. Должно помочь.